# Removing unecessary double quotes from keys in a dictionary - Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, collections, double-quotes

The goal of my program is to create a dictionary of items (key) and their count (values). The keys are extracted from a text file, in which they're organized as lists.

*Example*: ['synonymous_variant'] ['splice_region_variant&synonymous_variant' ['synonymous_variant'] (each lists are on a new line, without any separators)

Code:

```
from collections import Counter
file = open('/home/becquart/Stagiaire_refinement_construct_peptides/Travail5/RE__[Allogenomics]_travail_Vcf/results.txt', 'r').read()

for char in '""-.,\n[]':
    file = file.replace(char,' ')

for i in char:
    file = file.replace('""', ' ')


file = file.lower()

word_list = file.split()

d = dict(Counter(word_list).most_common())

print d
```

The output is something like: `{"'coding_sequence_variant&3_prime_utr_variant'": 6, "'inframe_insertion&nmd_transcript_variant'": 17` etc.

I would like to remove `"` from the keys, but I am having a hard time figuring it out as I'm very new in programming...I would be extremely happy if I could get this solved.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**: 
Input file here: https://ufile.io/v1tm0

Comment: Please show a proper code-formatted example of the input data.

Comment: Isn't it just this you are looking for `file = file.replace('"', '')`?

Comment: Rather than removing the quotes, why don't you ensure they are *not* added initially?

Comment: @Chris_Rands why should we assume they have any control over input data?

Comment: @PaxVobiscum Well that's why I'm asking the question; this problem is best fixed upstream

Comment: Just a remark: if you print a dict, Python will automatically add quotes around strings...

Comment: I have uploaded my input file, if that helps everyone.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum I have previously tried this idea. However it did not work. Thanks